# Collecting data from multiple sources using multiple processes/threads/tasks

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Let's imagine the set of several data sources, i.e. couple of thermal sensors, or video cameras. I want to collect data from those sources in slaves and pass to the master.

Efficiency is the key aspect of the operation.

Should I use multiple processes or threads/tasks?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention... All data sources should be synchronously served, equally with the same priority, at the same time, regardless of the CPU and memory usage and available number of cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing from several slaves to a master, use threads. This will help you share your address space and perhaps make the task easier to implement. If you have very many slaves and want the utmost efficiency, use a thread pool to service slave sources.

Using multiple processes would just add process context switch overhead, which in general is slightly more than that of thread context switches. You would also have to manage interprocess communication, which in general is more complex and less efficient than interthread communication.

Comment: In fact, the concept of multiple threads is much more easier to handle. I considered the Memory Mapped Files to exchange data. It could work with interprocess communication. I don't know if it is suitable for threads. What do you think about that?

Comment: File mapping objects are most likely your best option for efficient interprocess communication, which you should still avoid. One of the reasons it would be less efficient than interthread communication is that you would have to use a mutex for synchronization to the file mapping object, instead of the much more efficient critical section.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of doing that is using a reader writer lock ([ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) in .NET). Your writers would queue for one-at-a-time write access to your shared state map, while your readers (your client application for instance) can read together at the same time, though obviously not while the state is being written by a producer.

Edit: That's using threads obviously. Inter process communication would kill any hope of decent performance you might have.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Can you please see the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402469/collecting-data-from-multiple-sources-using-multiple-processes-threads-tasks#comment13418611_10402490

Comment: Doesn't exactly change much, you just have a set of events you fire off for every producer, and your consumer joins on all of them, then it fires another event that the producers join on when done. You still need to serialize the actual access to your object, although a simple `lock(syncobj)` might be enough with only one consumer.